# Mean and variance of call center data

Tags: probability, self-study, variance, mean

I have a fairly involved homework question, I was wondering if I could get some help.

> There are two types of phone calls arriving at a switch, long-duration and short-duration. Each day the number of calls is observed up to and including the first long-duration call. This was done for 8 days and the information gathered is as follows: 15, 6, 9, 12, 18, 3, 15, 21.
>
> a) Compute the probability of observing long and short duration calls.
>
> b) If 100 calls are made on each day, compute the mean and the variance of the number of long and short duration calls on each day.
>
> c) If the average length of a long duration call is 60 minutes and the average length of a short duration call is 3 minutes, compute the effective average length of a call.

The way I did part a was by adding 1/15 + 1/6 ... (since this is the prob of getting a long-duration with the sample data provided) and then dividing by 8 to get 0.116 prob of observing a long-duration. and 1-0.116 to observe a short-duration.

To do b I took (1/15)x100, (1/6)x100, ... to find the number of long-duration calls in 100 and then found the mean and variance of those numbers. I'm not confident about this method. I got a mean of 11.636 and variance of 91.553 for long-duration (the variance should be the same of short and long duration, yeah?) But now that I think about it looks like the question is asking about each day separately.

I think c was pretty simple. I just took (1/15)x60 + (14/15)x30 + (1/6)x60 + (5/6)x30 +... and then divided that sum by 8 to get 6.591 as the average length of a call.

I know there is a lot there, any help is much appreciated. Thank you!